# How to Include a child data's child object in .Net Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

this is my first question. I'm happy to be here.
The question that confused me when I was considering whether to become a member for a long time forced me to become a member.

I have a project, my data class like it :

```
public class Transactions
{
    public int trnid { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentTransactionId")]
    public virtual List<Transactions> ParentTransaction { get; set; }
    public int? ParentTransactionId { get; set; }
}
```

Something like it. I've have a generic repository. This is like that.

```
public Result<List<T>> SelectInclude(Expression<Func<T, object>>[] IncludeParameters, Expression<Func<T, bool>> Filter = null)
{
}
```

And I use include methods like that.

```
if (IncludeParameters != null)
{
     queryable = IncludeParameters.Aggregate(queryable, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
}
```

This works pretty well. I pass include parameters like that.

```
object>>[]
{
   x => x.ParentTransaction,
},
```

How do I get more than child-objects?

```
ParentTransaction.Select(aa=> aa.ParentTransaction);
```

But this is not correct, I am getting error using this methods.

Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: You were *forced* to join? Does their cruelty know no bounds?

Comment: You will have to (greatly) complicate your `SelectInclude` to analyze the member access and use `ThenInclude`.

Comment: Actually I can use "string[] includeParameters" instead of "Expression<Func<T, object>>[] IncludeParameters." Then I can add parameters like that :  entites = entites.Include(includeParameters[i]). But I want to use Expression methods.

Comment: I don't see how that will help unless `string` `Include` will process nested references for you?

Comment: I see that it does... I think for `Expression` based paths, you could use the code from the EF Core string based includes (I see some discussion [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/3921)) as a basis.

Comment: I don't know if it's the right solution but I solved my problem the way I wrote it.

Comment: https://code-maze.com/net-core-web-development-part4/#repoWrapper